# Flink schema evolution not working for POJO class

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink

I have a class that fulfills the requirements to be treated as POJO,
and this is the main transport class in my streaming job
(it only contains primitives and a `Map<String, String>`).
I have added a new `String` field and the corresponding getter and setter,
but if I stop the job that's using the previous class with a savepoint and try to use it to restart with the new class,
I get an exception:

```
 java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:195)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:253)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:901)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:415)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for WindowOperator_3b2dbb810ac7d55949cb205a3075facc_(8/8) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:135)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:307)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:135)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.state.BackendBuildingException: Failed when trying to restore heap backend
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.MemoryStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(MemoryStateBackend.java:347)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:291)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:142)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:121)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 172199998, Size: 13
...
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:761)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:346)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer.deserialize(ListSerializer.java:133)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.base.ListSerializer.deserialize(ListSerializer.java:42)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTableByKeyGroupReaders.lambda$createV2PlusReader$0(StateTableByKeyGroupReaders.java:77)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupPartitioner$PartitioningResultKeyGroupReader.readMappingsInKeyGroup(KeyGroupPartitioner.java:297)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.readKeyGroupStateData(HeapRestoreOperation.java:293)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.readStateHandleStateData(HeapRestoreOperation.java:254)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapRestoreOperation.restore(HeapRestoreOperation.java:154)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.build(HeapKeyedStateBackendBuilder.java:114)
        ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 172199998, Size: 13
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.MapReferenceResolver.getReadObject(MapReferenceResolver.java:42)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readReferenceOrNull(Kryo.java:805)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:728)
        at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:113)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
```

For some reason it's falling back on Kryo.

I am using Flink 1.9.3, and [according to the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/state/schema_evolution.html) this change should be supported.

---

Based on David's answer, I'm trying to see if I can migrate my state on the fly *before* adding the new field to the class.
I've added the `@TypeInfo` annotation and its factory to `MyPojo`,
and I'm trying to migrate state like this:

```
lsd = new ListStateDescriptor<>(
        "newName",
        MyPojo.class
);

// migration

TypeToken<LabeledClassWithTimestamp<String>> typeToken = new TypeToken<LabeledClassWithTimestamp<String>>() {};
ListStateDescriptor<LabeledClassWithTimestamp<String>> legacyLSD = new ListStateDescriptor<>(
        "oldName",
        new KryoSerializer<>((Class<LabeledClassWithTimestamp<String>>) typeToken.getRawType(), runtimeContext.getExecutionConfig())
);

ListState<LabeledClassWithTimestamp<String>> legacyState = runtimeContext.getListState(legacyLSD);
try {
    List<MyPojo> newState = new ArrayList<>();
    legacyState.get().forEach(o -> newState.add((MyPojo) o));

    if (!newState.isEmpty()) {
        runtimeContext.getListState(lsd).update(newState);
        legacyState.clear();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Could not migrate state:", e);
}
```

However, if I restore the job from a previous savepoint using the new jar,
Flink throws a `StateMigrationException` *in a different operator*:

```
2020-11-08T12:57:59.369Z INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph:1511 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] window-operator (1/8) (uid) switched from RUNNING to FAILED. org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: For heap backends, the new state serializer must not be incompatible.
```

That operator's state only holds integers:

```
public class SlidingWindowProcessFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<MyPojo, MyOutput, String, TimeWindow> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private static final ListStateDescriptor<Integer> LSD = new ListStateDescriptor<>(
            "window-state", Integer.class);
    
    ...
    
    @Override
    public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<MyPojo> iterable, Collector<MyOutput> collector) {
        ...
        for (Integer hash : context.windowState().getListState(LSD).get()) {
            alreadyProcessedHashes.add(hash);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Is `MyPojo`'s serializer relevant for this other operator's state even though the POJO class is not used directly in its managed state?

Comment: Just to confirm, logs from the workflow with the previous version of your POJO do NOT contain any INFO messages that look like `Class <your class> cannot be used as a POJO type...`

Comment: @kkrugler that's right, I did verify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to make sense of what's going on internally in Flink,
but I found a way to achieve migration in 2 upgrades,
although I don't really understand why it works.

In the first upgrade I don't add any new field to the POJO class,
but I add the type information that David suggested.
The critical thing in my case was that,
since my initial job could not be modified anymore and the POJO didn't have the annotations,
the type information for the `Map` in the `TypeInfoFactory` had to point to Kryo:

```
put("mapField", Types.GENERIC(Map.class));
```

I then added a new state descriptor without modifying the old one (my old state was defined in terms of an interface):

```
ListStateDescriptor<InterfaceWithGeneric<String>> legacyLSD = new ListStateDescriptor<>(
        "oldName",
        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<InterfaceWithGeneric<String>>() {})
);

ListStateDescriptor<MyPojo> newLSD = new ListStateDescriptor<>(
        "newName",
        MyPojo.class
);
```

With that I can read from the old descriptor and initialize the new one as needed.

In the second upgrade I can remove the old descriptor and add the new field to the POJO,
updating the `TypeInfoFactory` as well.
Serialization of the existing map will have to continue using Kryo,
as I couldn't find a way to modify that.

Adding the annotations, the new field, and the new descriptor in one upgrade didn't work for me.
I also couldn't reuse the old descriptor;
the first upgrade would work fine,
but adding a new field in the second upgrade threw exceptions again.
I don't know why some of the exceptions were referencing completely unrelated operators,
but it seems to just be erroneous reporting from the state restore backend.

Comment: Glad you found a way to move forward.

Answer (score 4):

Flink will accept a class as a valid POJO type even if it contains a field (such as a LIST or MAP) that it cannot serialize without falling back to Kryo. In such cases the INFO log message about `Class <your class> cannot be used as a POJO type ...` will not appear, but the class will not be fully supported for state migration.

Flink can deal with LIST and MAP types in POJO fields, but doesn't do so automatically (in order to avoid breaking backwards compatibility).

You can get this working cleanly by annotating your class with `@TypeInfo` and implementing a `TypeInfoFactory<T>` for it that specifies the correct `org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types` for each field, including the `org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types#MAP`.

That might look something like this:

```java
@TypeInfo(MyPojo.MyPojoTypeInfoFactory.class)
public class MyPojo {
  private String data;
  private HashMap<String, String> attributes;

  public static class MyPojoTypeInfoFactory extends TypeInfoFactory<MyPojo> {
    @Override
    public TypeInformation<MyPojo> createTypeInfo(
        Type t, Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> genericParameters) {
      Map<String, TypeInformation<?>> fields =
          new HashMap<String, TypeInformation<?>>() {
            {
              put("data", Types.STRING);
              put("attributes", Types.MAP(Types.STRING, Types.STRING));
            }
          };
      return Types.POJO(MyPojo.class, fields);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that a Types.MAP field must not be null. Null keys are not allowed in the map, but null values are okay.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but unfortunately it's not working for me. My "old" job has been released, so I cannot change that, and adding the type information in the new jar only (with the new field added to the class) doesn't seem to be enough, since I get an exception `StateMigrationException: For heap backends, the new state serializer must not be incompatible.`. I don't know if field order is relevant, but I've tried many different orders in the fields provided to the factory (and changed the `fields` map to a `LinkedHashMap`), but I always get the aforementioned exception.

Comment: Yes, I was explaining how you might’ve avoided the problem you are in, not how to repair the current situation. For that you might be able to use the state processor api to migrate the state from the old serializer to a new one.

Comment: I'm thinking I could use a [`TypeSerializerSnapshot`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/stream/state/custom_serialization.html#the-typeserializersnapshot-abstraction) that returns `org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer` in its `restoreSerializer` method and migrates to something that supports evolution (like kryo's `VersionFieldSerializer`), but it seems `TypeSerializer` can only be specified for each `StateDescriptor`, there's no way to configure that globally?

Comment: I believe you can register a custom Kryo serializer for a given class, and then any state descriptors for the class will use the serializer that's been registered. You can do this via `registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(Class<?>, Class<? extends Serializer>)`. Look at `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer`.

Comment: I've updated the question adding what I've tried, I don't know if you have further ideas.

Comment: I'm not sufficiently familiar with the issues here, but this section of the docs may help: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/stream/state/custom_serialization.html

Comment: I think I found a way to make it work, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Our Flink project also encountered a similar issue as yours.

We basically had a corruptive POJO class(where getter/setter names weren't correct). And if we want to fix the naming of the getter/setter, plus update the currently running application with a snapshot. We get messages like this:
[ListSerializer incompatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjTIZ.png)

Some detail regarding our project is that the corruptive POJO class mentioned above is nested in another top-level POJO class. And the top-level POJO class is fed to a Cogroup Function as an iterable. We are using google guava to instantiate the iterable into ArrayList.

Back to your experience, for those 2 StateDescriptors, I have some questions and hope you can answer them.

```html
ListStateDescriptor<InterfaceWithGeneric<String>> legacyLSD = new ListStateDescriptor<>(
        "oldName",
        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<InterfaceWithGeneric<String>>() {})
);

ListStateDescriptor<MyPojo> newLSD = new ListStateDescriptor<>(
        "newName",
        MyPojo.class
);
```

1. Why do we need ListStateDescriptor here instead of ValueStateDescriptor.
2. Did you declare them in the RichFunction(let's say RichMapFunction, RichCoGroupFunction, etc.)? And if so, are there any more code snippets where you used them? Or simple declaration will help with the problematic serializer?

Thanks!

Comment: The type of state (List or Value) doesn't matter, as far as I know, that's just the type I was using. I don't have that code anymore but I don't think I did anything special besides declaring them.

Comment: Hi @Alxis, thanks for your reply. For the `InterfaceWithGeneric<String>` and `MyPojo`, do they refer to the same POJO class?
Does it mean the legacyLSD was already there before any changes happened?

Comment: `legacyLSD` was there already, and it's important that its name doesn't change ("oldName" in this example). `newLSD` can have any name and it doesn't have to use the same POJO class, if I recall correctly. Something I didn't mention is the wait time before upgrade 1 and 2 - since I had to read from old state and update new at runtime, I couldn't update all keys at the same time, so I had to wait a significant time between upgrades. I suppose this could be avoided with the state processor API.

Comment: Hi Alexis. We actually have our Flink deployed to AWS KDA. And they do not provide snapshot files, so sadly we cannot rely on State processor API. But I think the wait time is a good hint. we have read something about the state TTL and will probably start looking into it. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, did you still have the try-catch block when successfully updating the applications?

Comment: You mean the one I showed in the test where I explicitly used `KryoSerializer`? No, I think that try-catch wasn't strictly needed in the end, and I of course didn't end up using the kryo serializer explicitly.

Comment: Yes exactly, we are trying to re-implement that part. We do try out providing TypeInformation to the POJO class as well.
The update from the original version to the one with type information still throws state incompatible exceptions.
But if we have the TypeInformation one as the first version, we can freely update the POJO class in the following version.
In this case, we have to find out a way to update the current version to come along with the type information. But thanks for your clarification!

Comment: If you're trying to keep the same class but add type information, you might actually have to instantiate `KryoSerializer` explicitly for the old descriptor (and only for the old one). If you add the type info annotation to the existing class then Flink will try to use it for the existing state as well (I think), so I imagine you have to override that if your class doesn't change but the annotation is added.

Comment: The difference here is that we do not have any states explicitly declared in the current prod version. So we're not sure how to get access to the old state except for creating a new state.