# What happens to keyed window-global state without TTL if a key is never seen again?

Tags: apache-flink

Flink's `ProcessWindowFunction` can use so-called [global state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#using-per-window-state-in-processwindowfunction) with something like `context.globalState().getState`.
Usually, such state could grow and shrink as time moves forward,
but what happens if global state *without* TTL was created for a key and that key is never seen again?
According to the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl),
TTL cannot be added during upgrade,
so the state will stay there forever?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.

Comment: For completeness, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64741856/5793905) I posted could allow migration to state with TTL.