# Distributed execution with Apache Flink and (de)serialization of class fields/members

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple proof of concept for a Flink job. It basically receives messages (in JSON format) from a Kafka topic, deserialize them into a domain model, validate these against some predefined set of rules, applies some transformations, and finally publishes a resultant message into a Kafka sink.

I do have several functions/operators that use some behavior from other "service" classes. Those "service" classes could import some other dependencies as well.

As far as I know, Flink will try to (de)serialize those functions/operators in order to make the entire job truly distributed. I'm not clear if Flink would automatically avoid that by using `transient` on those fields/members or if it would be enough to declare them as `static` to avoid that.

This is an example of what I have:

```java
public final class SomeFlatMapFunction implements FlatMapFunction<SomeMessage, Some> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5810858761065889162L;

  private static final SomeMapper MAPPER = SomeMapper.INSTANCE;

  private static final Validator VALIDATOR = Validator.INSTANCE;

  @Override
  public void flatMap(final SomeMessage value, final Collector<Some> out) {
    final var result = MAPPER.valueFrom(value);
    final var violations = VALIDATOR.getValidator().validate(result);
    if (violations.isEmpty()) {
      out.collect(result);
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't seen any issues with this so far, but I'm just running the application locally. What's the best/accepted approach here, even for those case where one could have to inject those dependencies in the function's constructor? It looks very much that maintaining state between those functions is highly discouraged as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators do get serialized and deserialized,
that's why there are several `Rich*` versions of the operators with `open` and `close` methods,
they can be used to set up things *after* deserialization,
once the operator is already in the task manager where it will run.
Flink will respect Java's usual serialization rules and will not serialize `static` or `transient` members.

In my experience, injecting domain classes in operators' constructors isn't a problem.
Where you need to be careful is with domain classes that go through the network while the job is running,
what sometimes is referred to as Data Transfer Objects.
For those, the simplest thing is to implement them as POJOs, where 2 things are critical:

- They must have a no-argument constructor.
- They should be annotated with type information. See an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64721838/5793905).

The second is particularly important if such POJOs will be part of your application's *state*,
i.e. if you are using Flink's managed state API.

And somethig you already considered:
adding `serialVersionUID` is also a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your throughout answer! The usual domain classes I knew they would have to, because that's usually the data that flows between the functions/operators, so if they are meant to be distributed there aren't many choices there. But the reason I thought all those custom `FlatMapFunction`, `FilterFunction`, etc. behave as well similarly was because they all extend from `Serializable`, so there should be a reason for that. Now I'm even more confused ;/

Comment: @x80486 I'd guess the operators don't go through the same serialization stack, but that's not something I know for sure. They do need to be serializable though, even if they are serialized differently. I suppose extending `Serializable` is a good way to make sure there won't be weird conflicts.